# How to script a command to make a single-user copy of a Texture (withoug pressing the correspoinding button)

Tags: scripting

If I have many objects with the same texture and I would like to make a single-user copy for every object, it would be very tedious to do it by hand, clicking the button next to the texture's name, thus I would like to script this.

I know of the command

```py
bpy.ops.object.make_single_user(type='SELECTED_OBJECTS', object=True, obdata=True)
```

It can be used to copy materials, actions and other things, but I didn't achieve an application to textures, I don't know if this is possible.

Maybe it would be possible to make a copy of a texture from a previous object but I don't know how to script this.

Comment: From [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=make_single_user#bpy.ops.object.make_single_user) you just need to add `material=True` in your command for blender 2.81

Comment: This just makes a single-user copy of the material, I would like to make a copy of the texture, which is used in the displace modifier for example.